# Cannot import database exported by phpPgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, phppgadmin

I have exported database with phpPgAdmin tool - format sql, structure and data.

When I try to import this sql using:

**psql command \i filename.sql**

After some time (file is 2GB) I get following error:

*ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near ".. , '\x25504... "*

with "arrow" pointing to \x.

Looks like \ is making a problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this tutorial](https://jelastic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206122146-How-to-export-PostgreSQL-database-from-phpPgAdmin), seems like `phpPgAdmin` make a call for `pg_dump` to export the data.

To process plain files with `psql`, you must use the `-f`option, eg:

```
psql \
  -U postgres  \
  -d database_name \
  -f phppgadmin_dump_file.sql
```

I strongly recommend using `pg_dump` manually with the option `--format=custom` to make the restore more flexible (and use the tool `pg_restore`).

Please, take a look at this URL to restore de file using `phpPgAdmin` itself:

- http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/postgresql/import-database

Comment: I will accept this answer because it's valid. My problem was that database was/is on jelastic and with default settings (no public ip) I cannot directly access the database with pg_dump tool... I ended up changing that ip setting and "re-dumped" the database with -Fc option and it worked.